# SQL Insert line break

Tags: php

How can i insert line break by a variable inserting into mysql?

```
$delattn = $row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_fname'].' '.$row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_lname'].',
 '.$row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_designation'].',
```

> LINE BREAK

```
'.$row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_department'];
```

Comment: This isn't "mysql".  PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a "\n" where you want a line break

```
$delattn = $row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_fname'].' '.$row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_lname'].','.$row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_designation'].', \n     '.$row_Recordset_delattn['Cus_department'];
```

Use PHP's

```
nl2br()
```

function to translate that line break into a

```
<br />
```

tag in HTML. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)